# how to match two columns in a join by a third "mapping" table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to do a VLOOKUP like join in sql.

I have 3 table:

dest_table:  [image: destination_test_name | des_string_result]

target_table: [image]

map_table: [image]

Wanted output:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this using joins.

```
select 
    destination_test_name,
    des_string_result,
    target_test_name,
    target_string_result
from 
    map_table 
    inner join dest_table using(destination_test_name)
    inner join target_table using(target_test_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select d.destination_test_name, des_string_result, m.target_test_name, t.target_string_result 
from dest_table as d
inner join map_table as m
on m.destination_test_name = d.destination_test_name
inner join target_table as t
on t.target_test_name = m.target_test_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Please, use below query with outer join :

```
select 
    MT.destination_test_name,
    DT.des_string_result,
    MT.target_test_name,
    TT.target_string_result
from 
    map_table MT
    left outer join dest_table DT on MT.destination_test_name = DT.destination_test_name
    left outer join target_table TT on MT.destination_test_name = TT.target_test_name;
```